# `System.Xml.Linq` consumes a massive amount of memory

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, .net-core

It appears that `System.Xml.Linq` is consuming an enormous amount of memory, even after any resources should be freed.
A simple demonstration

```cs
await using ( System.IO.FileStream stream = new ( xmlFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open) ) {
    using ( System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create( stream, new () { ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment, Async = true } ) ) {
        int i = 0;
        while ( await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait( false ) ) {
            while ( reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.None ) {
                if ( reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration ) {
                    await reader.SkipAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
                    continue;
                }
                if ( ct.IsCancellationRequested ) {
                    continue;
                }
                i++;
                if ( i % 100000 == 0 ) {
                    Console.WriteLine( $"Processed {i}: {reader.ReadString()}" );
                }
                System.Xml.Linq.XNode node = await System.Xml.Linq.XNode.ReadFromAsync( reader, ct ).ConfigureAwait( false );

            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine( $"\n---->Memory Use/false: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false):N0}");
Console.WriteLine( $"---->Memory Use      : {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):N0}\n");
return;
```

Outputs:

```
---->Memory Use/false: 402,639,448
---->Memory Use      : 400,967,152
```

If I replace the `XNode` portion,

```cs
                        string xmlFilePath = "/home/eric/dev/src/github.com/erichiller/mkmrk-dotnet/src/Cli/dataset/cme/definition/2021/11/2021-11-05/20211104.061134-05_20211104.030927-05_cmeg.nymex.fut.prf.xml";
                        
await using ( System.IO.FileStream stream = new ( xmlFilePath, System.IO.FileMode.Open) ) {
    using ( System.Xml.XmlReader reader = System.Xml.XmlReader.Create( stream, new () { ConformanceLevel = System.Xml.ConformanceLevel.Fragment, Async = true } ) ) {
        int i = 0;
        while ( await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait( false ) ) {
            while ( reader.NodeType != System.Xml.XmlNodeType.None ) {
                if ( reader.NodeType == System.Xml.XmlNodeType.XmlDeclaration ) {
                    await reader.SkipAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
                    continue;
                }
                if ( ct.IsCancellationRequested ) {
                    continue;
                }
                i++;
                if ( i % 100000 == 0 ) {
                    Console.WriteLine( $"Processed {i}: {reader.ReadString()}" );
                }
                await reader.ReadAsync().ConfigureAwait( false );
            }
        }
    }
}
Console.WriteLine( $"\n---->Memory Use/false: {GC.GetTotalMemory(false):N0}");
Console.WriteLine( $"---->Memory Use      : {GC.GetTotalMemory(true):N0}\n");
return;
```

The use drops considerably:

```
---->Memory Use/false: 11,048,992
---->Memory Use      : 6,317,248
```

What am I misunderstanding here / doing wrong? The file being loaded is large (~60MB) but even if XNode needed to use that much memory, shouldn't it be released by the time `Console.WriteLine` is reached?

Comment: no - its non deterministic - .net is gc'd and things aren't always deallocated from the heap once blocks are closed

Comment: Out of curiosity why don’t you call break; instead of continue; when cancellation token cancels?

Comment: I ended up re-writing to use XmlReader directly and not through System.Xml.Linq ; much better performance and memory consumption (~40MB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linq to XML eagerly loads the whole XML document into memory, creating many objects to represent it. You appear to be doing that many times in a loop while reading - without much protecting the recursive traversal.

However, using an `XmlReader`, that allows for manual control and it only reads enough information and allows the consumer to decide what to do with it.

*Memory is not always freed when blocks are closed. Things on the heap will be cleaned up by GC at some point.*

Comment: But OP is calling GetTotalMemory with the argument forceFullCollection = true and the GC didn’t cleanup as OP desires

Comment: @RandRandom true but there’s probably a lot of fragmentation and it’s an implementation detail of how gc works

Comment: @RandRandom You need to do GC *outside* of the function which holds the data, or GC may not release it

Comment: @Charlieface putting the XML code outside the method doing the GC doesn't change the result. I tried just to be sure.

Comment: but as I understood the question, OP doesn’t mind the memory consumption if OP has a valid way to free the memory after the code got executed, currently you have only answered one part of the question, what the difference is between the two methods but not why the memory doesn’t get released

Comment: @Charlieface then OP would need to know how to successfully free the memory, as I understood it, this is part of the question

Comment: I believe this answered my question, particularly _Linq to XML eagerly loads the whole XML document into memory_